# Async wait Fetch gives undefined

Tags: node.js, json, async-await, fetch, svelte

I am using Svelte and Node.js for my project. I am trying to read JSON file from URL and display it on the client-side, which I'm using Svelte.

I am using async wait function and it gives me undefined as it does not read my function.

DataService.js

```
    let data;
;(async ()=>{
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tables.json');
    data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
})()

export const getTable = () => {
    return data;
}
```

Catalog.svelte

```
<script>
import {getTable} from '../components/dataservice.js';

console.log(getTable());

</script>
```

It returned me undefined out of sudden. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not make `getTable` the async function?

Comment: As fetch is asynchronous, there's no guarantee that it will be resolved by the time `getTable` returns `data`. So most likely, it would *always* return `undefined`.